# Cache-Control headers not sent in response despite being configured on response object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-caching

I'm trying to set cache headers in ASP.NET MVC Web API, but the response from IIS suggests that the CacheControl values set are being ignored.

My original assumption was that I was using the EnableCorsAttribute in System.Web.Http.Cors, which is necessary in this use case. However, even without that attribute, the response Cache-Control header is still 'private'.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

```
    // GET api/<version>/content
    // [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        int cacheMaxAgeSeconds;

        string cacheMaxAgeString = request.GetQueryString("cache-max-age") ?? request.GetQueryString("cache-max-age-seconds");

        string rawUri = request.RequestUri.ToString();

        try
        {
            cacheMaxAgeSeconds = cacheMaxAgeString == null ? Config.ApiCacheControlMaxSeconds : int.Parse(cacheMaxAgeString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cacheMaxAgeSeconds = Config.ApiCacheControlMaxSeconds;

            //... 
        }

        try
        {
            //...

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("...", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
            {
                Public = true,
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(cacheMaxAgeSeconds)
            };

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception apiEx)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 10:53:17 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=knjh4pncbrhad30kjykvwxyz; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 2367
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: is there a reason you are trying to roll your own here over something like https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache  ?

Comment: Yes, I actually want the caller to be able to specify the cache period. The value is read from the query string and feeds into the cache control header values.

Comment: hmm, if anyone will know the answer to this one it will be https://twitter.com/filip_woj  (creator of above nuget package) might be worth reaching out to him on twitter.

Comment: Good call. Before I do that I will have a look through that project and see if anything is done differently. Will update when I've had a chance to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer, having picked this up some weeks later:

Cache-Control header appears to be set to 'private' when running **debug** builds. The issue goes away when I run with a release build.

Answer (score 6):

Code below sets "cache-control: public, max-age=15" correctly in vanilla WebApi application (System.Web.Http 4.0.0.0). So... it's probably not the WebApi itself that causes the issue.

You may have some magic in your project that changes cache settings (think of global action filters or something similar). Or maybe you are going through proxy which rewrites HTTP headers.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var content = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { foo = "bar" });

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
        };

        return response;
    }

// returns in the response: "Cache-Control: public, max-age=15"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another thing that can cause this:

You run through an Owin pipeline.

In that case, you need to set the headers in an Owin middleware defined as this:

```
class MiddleWare : OwinMiddleware
{
    public MiddleWare(OwinMiddleware next)
    : base(next)
    {
    }
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
        context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ran into an issue with IE11 aggressively caching ajax responses and this middleware did the trick. Thanks!